# Intents in android

Tags: android

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String S = b.getString("key1");
        t1.setText(S);
        try {
            wait(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i2 = new Intent();
        i2.putExtra("reply","Everything is cool");
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i2);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is my second Activity code. Actually, I was seeing how intent works by implementing a very basic program. Program is working without wait, but the app is crashing if I put wait function. provide me some way so that i can stay on to the second activity for a longer time before sending back the r

Comment: The onCreate method is called on android main thread. You cannot block the main thread by sleep, wait, network op or a disk op. For these kind of operation, you can use AsyncTasks, Handlers, RxJava etc.

Comment: If my post was helpful to you then you can mark it as a answer so it would be helpful for others.

Comment: you can use service or acyncTask instead of "  try {
            wait(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }"

Answer (score 1):

Use `Handler` and try to start Intent from run() You can check below example,

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override 
         public void run() { 
              Intent i2 = new Intent();
              i2.putExtra("reply","Everything is cool");
              setResult(RESULT_OK,i2);
              finish(); 
         } 
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use service or acyncTask instead of

```
 try {
            wait(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You could try this code

```
   public void onclick(View v) {
    mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute();
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
```

Hope it will be helpful.